# c# how to only get updated objects from web api

Tags: c#, json, angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm polling data to my angular app from a c# web api. Every time all data is polled, even though much of the data haven't changed. I would like to poll only the objects which have actually been updated in any sort of way.

This is my code in my Controller.cs

```
 //Get all details of the available vehicles
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/details")]
        public object GetFleetStatusDetails()
        {

            var fmsData = this.fmsdb.Value.GetFleetStatusDetails();
            var data = fmsData.Entries;
            List<VehicleDetails> result = new List<VehicleDetails>();
            foreach (var item in data)
            { 
                if (item != null)
                {

                    var details = ConvertVehicleDetail(item);
                    result.Add(details);

                }

            }
            return result;
        }
```

As you can see im converting the data into VehicleDetails which I later add to my VehicleDetails list. The data im getting is in JSON-format. Is there a way of comparing my last poll with the current poll without going to much deeper down into the database? If so how would I do that?

Comment: Unless your database can notify you that the data is updated you will have to query the data to compare it with the last result, so I am tempted to say no for now.

Comment: @PeterBons Thanks for your reply! And I was about to go alittle further down, for example to my ApiService, would it be possible to do something over there?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest saving the last state either through the Browser's local storage or using ngrx.

Comment: Hello Jen! Thanks for your reply. If I'm using ngrx, I'll basically have to send all the data to the frontend, which is what I'm trying to do in the first place, right? Or in what way were you thinking I could ngrx?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `this.fmsdb.Value.GetFleetStatusDetails();` does or the schema of the database you're calling the best guess answer would be to create two endpoints in the API.

The first would use `this.fmsdb.Value.GetFleetStatusDetails();` to get the full set of results. Once the data has been downloaded from the endpoint store the current date/time in the angular view and pass that to the second endpoint...

The second endpoint would get the records that have been changed since the date/time you got the first set of data. This assumes that you are storing the updated date time.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/updateddetails")]
public object GetUpdatedFleetStatusDetails([FromUrl]DateTime date)
{
    var fmsData = this.fmsdb.Value.GetUpdatedFleetStatusDetails(date);
    return fmsData.Entries
        .Where(x => x != null)
        .Select(ConvertVehicleDetail);
}
```

Could give more details if knew what was in this.fmsdb.Value.GetFleetStatusDetails()

PS Haven't tested this code.